# Vex dialog always closes after I click a button

Tags: javascript, dialog

I made a dialog with vex. The problem is that it closes after I click a button. Instead I want it to remain visible because it must perform other tasks. I tried to solve the problem with the following option

```
defaultOptions : { overlayClosesOnClick: false }
```

but it doesn't work. The entire code is below:

```
vex.dialog.open({
    message: 'my message', 
    input: [
        //these are textareas
        'my input 1',
        'my input 2'].join(''),
    buttons:[
        'my button 1',
        'my button 2'
    ],
    defaultOptions : { 
        //I thought that the following line would have done the trick
        overlayClosesOnClick: false 
    },
    callback: function (data) {...}});
```

Everytime I click a button it executes the callbak and closes, but I want it to remain open.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be adding the `onSubmit` function to the object and invoke the `preventDefault` method from there:

```
onSubmit:function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

The problem is that inside the `onSubmit` function I can't access `data`